# Azure Accounts - cannot see virtual environments that are in the parent account

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

We have a project in Azure and my manager has an Azure account setup with his email address.

When doing development work on Azure, this gets to be a pain in the backside because it starts to require 2 factor authentication.

I have tried to create a separate account using one of two methods, but neither of these work:

1 - Going into Active Directory, '+ New user' and then selecting 'Invite user'.   This does send an email to invite me to create a new account, however when it comes to actually setting up the account, it tends to fail.

2 - I have tried to create an account by going into Active Directory, '+ New user' and then selecting 'Create user'.   I have managed to give the user 'Admin access', however when I manage to login to Azure using this new user and its *.onmicrosoft.com email address, I cannot see the systems that exists in the parent account (eg the Virtual Servers etc).

This has been setup in Azure's free tier.

If you have any tips on what I am missing, I would be vert grateful.

Thanks

Mark

Comment: When you say you gave admin access, was it at AD level? You also need to go to your Azure subscription and grant explicit Owner/Contributor access to that account. There are two management planes, AD Roles and Azure RBAC.

Comment: As @KedMardemootoo suggested you have to add at subscription level. go to azure portal>>click on your subscription>> go to IAM>>go to role assignments and add him as a owner/contributor  or else add him as a co-administrator.